# my android video player has no errors but when launched shows blank screen

Tags: android, android-studio

This has been giving a problem for a while now and i dont know how to solve it
my code has absolutely no errors to the best of my knowledge but whenever i test it all it shows me is a blank white screen any ideas why and how i can stop it because i have a deadline.

here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.android.beez.play;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<String> videoPath= new ArrayList<String>();
String ext=".3gp";
String ext2=".mp4";
final Context context=this;

public class GenericExtFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    private String ext;

    public GenericExtFilter(String ext) {
        this.ext = ext;
    }

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(ext));
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    File files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/");
    Log.i("files.........",files.toString());
    GenericExtFilter filter = new GenericExtFilter(ext);
    String[] list = files.list(filter);
    GenericExtFilter filter2 = new GenericExtFilter(ext2);
    String[] list2 = files.list(filter2);

    for(int i=0;i<list.length | i<list2.length;++i)
    {
        videoPath.add(i,list[i].toString());
        videoPath.add(i+1,list2[i].toString());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,            R.layout.activity_main,videoPath));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int
        position, long id) {             
            String path="/mnt/sdcard/";
            path=path+videoPath.get(position);
            Log.i("path of video file......",path);
            video(path);
        }
    });
}

public void video(String path)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(context,PlayVideo.class);
    i.putExtra("path",path);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

and my activity_main

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:background="#000000"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:context="com.android.beez.play.MainActivity"
   tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#0432bc">


   </TextView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

and my video_layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#000000">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Back to List"
    android:background="#0432bc"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my PlayVideo.java

```
package com.android.beez.play;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class PlayVideo extends Activity {
Button back;
final Context context=this;
VideoView v;
String path;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
    back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    v=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    path=i.getStringExtra("path");
    Log.i("path of video file......", path);
    v.setVideoPath(path);

    v.setMediaController(new MediaController(context));
    v.requestFocus();

    v.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            v.start();
        }
    });

    v.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.reset();
            v.setVideoPath(path);
            v.start();
        }
        });
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method.

Comment: i tried but it only made things worse the app refused to launch at all it only gave me the error message

Comment: What error message did it give? `setContentView` has to be called in order for the activity to know which layout it's supposed to show.